# Insert image in HTML without shifting of text

Tags: javascript, html

I've to insert a small image in between text using javascript. When I insert the image the text shifts right as the image comes in. I want to insert the image such that the text doesn't move or shift and the image superimpose it, using javascript. My current function is

```
var paraId = android.selection.getParagraphID();
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectionContents   = range.extractContents();
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.appendChild(selectionContents);
span.setAttribute("class","uiWebviewHighlight");
span.style.backgroundColor  = "blue";
span.style.color = "white";
var spanID = 'SP' + paraId;
span.setAttribute("id",spanID);
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
image.height=5;
image.width=5;
image.align = "top";
image.style.position="relative";
span.appendChild(image);
range.insertNode(span);
```

Comment: Is this really a android related . or pure html and javascript ?

Comment: maybe `span.style.position="absolute";` ?

Comment: it is a javascript related problem, but am building it for android so i wanted an answer from android perspective which is feasible

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="test.png" style="float:right;">
```

You can put `float:left;` also in style.